# PHP Notice: Undefined offset error when importing from .csv

Tags: php, csv, undefined, offset, explode

I'm continually getting the above error when importing data from csv using the following code:

```
$csv_data=file_get_contents("data3_received.csv");
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $csv_data) as $line){
list($service_id, $ki3) = explode(',', $line,2);
```

The data imports as expected but the error log is filling up as we utilise the same code in multiple php scripts. The error is on the following line:

```
list($service_id, $ki3) = explode(',', $line,2);
```

Tried using the suggestion here: [Undefined offset error on php when importing a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246588/undefined-offset-error-on-php-when-importing-a-csv) to no avail, and other on the site.

Any help with this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `list()` is attempting to assign two variables it is attempting to access two array elements `[0]` and `[1]`. Because there is no comma on the line, `[1]` does not exist.

Try some different functions:

```
$csv_data = file("data3_received.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($csv_data as $line) {
    $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
```

To get individual variables you need to check if you have more than one column, or something similar:

```
if(count($data = str_getcsv($line)) > 1) {
    list($service_id, $ki3) = $data;
} else {
    $service_id = $data[0];
}
```

Comment: Able to run now with no errors but how can I use the data i.e. each column value as a variable?

Comment: Edited a possibility.

Comment: this does exactly what I need it to do, thank you!